# Toggle specific column in two-colum layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

Using CSS Flexbox I created a two-column layout that toggle's columns independent of each other. That's what I want. However, the way I did it just feels so impractical, because I need to set the height of the container in order to wrap the items in a two-column layout. I could ofcourse calculate the height based on number of columns, but yeah.. When I tried using row, both columns in the row collapsed/expanded. See code & design below. So, my question; is there a more elegant solution to this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-grid">
   @foreach($parents as $parent)
      <div class="col">
         <div class="header-group group-toggle" id="{{$parent->id}}">
            <h4><a href="{{ url($parent->url()) }}">{{ $parent->name }}</a></h4>
                 <div class="chev-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                  </div>
          </div>
        <div class="sub-group collapse in">
              @include('group.child', $parent)
        </div>
     </div>
   @endforeach
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-grid {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-content: center;
   height: 1200px;

   .col {
     width: 50%;
   }
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.group-toggle').on('click', function () {
    if ( !$(this).next().hasClass('in')) {
        $(this).parent().children('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    }

    $(this).next().collapse('group-toggle'); 
}
```

**Design**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should be a pretty quick fix. The concern you have about the height of the columns is directly addressed by the flexbox config.

Instead of using `column` flex direction and `wrap` for flex wrap...

```
flex-flow: column wrap; /* this is shorthand for flex-direction:column and flex-wrap: wrap */
```

...I would change the direction back to the default `row` and disallow wrapping. This will create a layout with each `.col` item having equal height:

```
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: no-wrap;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It will line up ALL .col items horizontally. This is not by the design.